# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to find out,
Which course has been done by most number of students?

```
create table studies(
PNAME varchar(20),
INSTITUTE varchar(20),
COURSE varchar(20),
COURSEFEE int
);

insert into studies values
('Anand','Sabhari','PGDCA',4500),
('Altaf', 'Coit','DCA',7200),
('Juliana', 'Bdps','MCA',2200),
('Kamala', 'Pragathi','DCA',5000),
('Mary', 'Sabhari','PGDCA',4500),
('Nelson', 'Pragathi','DAP',6200),
('Patrick', 'Pragathi','DCAP',5200),
('Qadir', 'Apple','HDCA',1400),
('Ramesh', 'Sabhari','PGDCA',4500),
('Rebecca', 'Brilliant','DCAP',11000),
('Remitha', 'Bdps','DCS',6000),
('Revathi', 'Sabhari','DAP',5000),
('Vijaya', 'Bdps','DCA',4800);
```

Query attempt:

```
SELECT COURSE
FROM STUDIES
GROUP BY COURSE
HAVING COUNT(COURSE)= (SELECT MAX(COUNT(COURSE))
FROM STUDIES
GROUP BY COURSE)
```

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to make your current version work, the subquery in the `HAVING` clause would need a bit more work:

```sql
SELECT COURSE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM STUDIES
GROUP BY COURSE
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(cnt)
                   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                         FROM STUDIES
                         GROUP BY COURSE) t);
```

Assuming you want the course having the max count, and you don't expect duplicates, you might be able to just use a `LIMIT` query here:

```sql
SELECT COURSE, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM STUDIES
GROUP BY COURSE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, you could use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` here, if your version of MySQL be 8 or later:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COURSE, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM STUDIES
    GROUP BY COURSE
)

SELECT COURSE, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: The `HAVING` clause can be simplified as: `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDIES GROUP BY COURSE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use as for single one:

```
SELECT COURSE FROM `STUDIES` HAVING COUNT(COURSE)
```

If you want for multiple:

```
SELECT COURSE
FROM STUDIES
GROUP BY COURSE
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(subject)
                  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS subject
                    FROM STUDIES
                    GROUP BY COURSE) rs
                  )
```